# How do you put mana symbols in your name?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2013, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2012, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2014

In all of the Magic the Gathering: Duals of the Planeswalker games so far, you can add mana symbols (and other symbols?) to your name using special character sequences.

**What are all the character sequences?**

Comment: One of them had a symbol at the beginning of the name, so when they spoke in the chat, I could see. As magic online, mana showed up as {U} or {W} for example. Problem is, if I try to type them they wont work. Did not try to put them in the name though.

Comment: @キキジキ Yeah, the symbols all have `{#}`, where `#` is some letter or number (possibly more than one??).  But there doesn't seem to be a list of them all online anywhere.

Comment: Note that this is for magic online http://www.wizards.com/Magic/Digital/MagicOnline.aspx?x=mtg/digital/magiconline/howdoi/talk

Answer (score 3):

According to [this post](http://steamcommunity.com/app/97330/discussions/0/846940248198384301/) on steam, this is what you have to use:

Anything enclosed in {} in your Steam Profile name will be interpreted by the game as a symbol. The mana symbols are BWRUG (black, white, red, blue and green respectively). X, 0-9, and k-p (lower-case) are colorless mana costs. Various other letters and punctuation produce other symbols, such as Xbox or PS buttons, arrows, etc.